# Showing scss file types in the Wordpress Admin UI

Tags: wordpress, sass

I am trying to show scss files in the WordPress admin UI, so I can edit them from there, like you do with PHP, CSS, or JS files. I have come across this filter, but it doesn't seem to work. I am running WordPress 4.9

```
add_filter('wp_theme_editor_filetypes', function ($types) {
    $types[] = 'scss';
    return $types;
});
```

Does anyone know why this would not function as expected?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:   This worked fine.... it was a cache issue I think.  Just didn't show up right away for me.